# How to create a key that identifies a set of numbers in order to retrieve a set in a collection if we do not have a key?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, set

I have several sets of numbers. I want to store these sets in a dictionary. I don't know how to generate a key that identifies the set in a unique way. In the case where I have a set without key, I want to generate automatically a key for that set and check if the generated key is in the dictionary.

Comment: this is very hard to understand without an example.

Comment: You can put the numbers in a frozenset or sort them and put them in a tuple.

Comment: @AlexHall For what reason sorting the numbers? Can avoid sorting the numbers if we want to identify in a unique way the set? Sorting thousands of numbers of a set is expensive.

Comment: Because the tuple `(1, 2, 3)` is not the same as `(1, 3, 2)`. To avoid sorting, use a frozenset.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `frozenset` as a dictionary key:

```
d = {frozenset([1, 2, 3]): 'a', frozenset([4, 5, 6]): 'b'}
print(d[frozenset([1, 2, 3])])  # 'a'
```

Comment: In this case frozenset([1, 2, 3]) is equal to frozenset([3,2,1])?

Comment: @nabiltos yes, you can check. Frozensets are just like sets, but they're immutable (frozen) and hashable.